# Read material text for multiple languages at the same time with READ_TEXT FM

Tags: abap, alv, sap-erp

I have managed to make the READ_TEXT FM work only for one cID at a time on multiple calls of function read_text(for example I found out how to access it for cID = 'GRUN' cObject = 'MATERIAL'. Can anyone advise how to connect read_text function so that inspection text(cID = 'GRUN' cObject = 'MATERIAL') will be dispalyed in my alv grid on the same line with material details?

[image: Please click here for output]

FORM READTEXT.

```
  data: it_MVKE type standard table of MVKE initial size 0.
  data: lMVKE like MVKE, lMAKT like MAKT, lT002 like T002 ,
        lTDNAME like THEAD-TDNAME,"text header

        it_TLINE type standard table of TLINE,
        wa_TLINE type TLINE.

  data: cObject(10) type c, cID(4) type c.


  select MATNR from MARA into corresponding fields of table it_MVKE
  where MATNR in Material order by MATNR.
  cID = 'GRUN'. cObject = 'MATERIAL'. "Text date principale "


  loop at it_MVKE into lMVKE.

    lTDNAME = lMVKE-MATNR.

    select spras from T002 into lT002.

      CALL FUNCTION 'READ_TEXT'
        EXPORTING
          CLIENT   = SY-MANDT
          ID       = cID
          LANGUAGE = lT002-SPRAS
          NAME     = lTDNAME
          OBJECT   = cObject
        TABLES
          LINES    = it_TLINE
        EXCEPTIONS
          ID       = 1
          OTHERS   = 8.

      IF SY-SUBRC EQ 0.

        select single * from MAKT into lMAKT where MATNR eq lMVKE-MATNR
         and SPRAS eq lT002-SPRAS.

        LOOP AT it_TLINE INTO wa_TLINE.
          wa_join-TEXTPRI = wa_TLINE-TDLINE.
          append wa_join to lt_join.
          clear wa_join.
        ENDLOOP.
      ENDIF.
    ENDSELECT.
  ENDLOOP.
ENDFORM.
```

Comment: What needs to work when `cID = PRUE ,cID =0001, cID = IVER`?

Comment: When values exist for any of below:                                                           
 cID =0001.  cObject = 'MVKE',                                                               
 cID = IVER. cObject = 'MATERIAL,                                                           
 cID = 'GRUN'. cObject = 'MATERIAL' .                                                    cID = PRUE. cObject = 'MATERIAL' .    I want to show them in my output table lt_join with whom i already show other fields in an ALV.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do like this. Function modules in SAP accept only single parameter at one time, unless this parameter is specified as a table type or in TABLES section.

However, here is workaround [from my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42270566/extracting-purchase-order-texts-in-sap/42280674#42280674) you can use to get rid of `READ_TEXT` at all.

1. As **forgetaboutme** said, put you cIDs into itab together with TDNAMEs:

   ```
   wa_cids-cid = 'GRUN'.
   wa_cids-cobject = 'MATERIAL'.
   if cID = '0001'.
    concatenate lMVKE-MATNR lMVKE-VKORG lMVKE-VTWEG into wa_cids-lTDNAME.
   else.
    lTDNAME = lMVKE-MATNR.
   endif.
   append wa_cids to it_cids.
   ```
2. Select texts from db table considering your itab.

   ```
   SELECT l~tdname l~clustr l~clustd
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE t_stxl
    FROM stxl AS l
    JOIN stxh AS h
     ON h~tdobject = l~tdobject
      AND h~tdname   = l~tdname
      AND h~tdid     = l~tdid
      FOR ALL ENTRIES it_cids
    WHERE l~relid    = 'TX'          "standard text
      AND h~tdobject = it_cids-cobject
      AND h~tdname   = it_cids-lTDNAME
      AND h~tdid     = it_cids-cid
      AND l~tdspras  = sy-langu.
   ```
3. Convert them from raw form into readable form

   ```
   CLEAR: t_stxl_raw[], t_tline[].
   APPEND VALUE ty_stxl_raw( clustr = <stxl>-clustr clustd = <stxl>-clustd ) TO t_stxl_raw.
   IMPORT tline = t_tline FROM INTERNAL TABLE t_stxl_raw.
   ```
4. Read them

   ```
   LOOP AT t_tline ASSIGNING <tline>.
    wa_Report-TEXT = <tline>-TDLINE.
   append wa_Report to it_Report.
   ENDLOOP.
   ```

Comment: Dear Suncatcher ,thank you for your response, i did as instructed but still facing an error : Fields <STXL>-CLUSTR is unknown. It is neither in one of the specified tables nor defined by a " DATA" statement.Please see my code modified in my initial question:

Comment: The errros is on line : w_stxl_raw-clustr = <stxl>-clustr.

Comment: You should run pts. 3 and 4 **inside a loop** through `t_stxl` table, `LOOP AT t_stxl ASSIGNING <stxl>.`, where `<stxl>` should have type of line of t_stx. Get all DATA definitions from my previous answer I provided.

Comment: Thank you again .I have done what you advised and still the same errorr :                                                                                        
  LOOP AT t_stxl ASSIGNING <stxl>.
  CLEAR: t_stxl_raw[], t_tline[].
w_stxl_raw-clustr = <stxl>-clustr.
w_stxl_raw-clustd = <stxl>-clustd.
APPEND w_stxl_raw TO t_stxl_raw.
IMPORT tline = t_tline FROM INTERNAL TABLE t_stxl_raw.


LOOP AT t_tline ASSIGNING <tline>.
 wa_Report-TEXT = <tline>-TDLINE.
append wa_Report to it_Report.
ENDLOOP.
  ENDLOOP.

Comment: The same means what? Did you declare `<stxl>` field-symbol? Try `LOOP AT t_stxl ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<stxl>).`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.You were right i didn`t declared <stxl> . i have declared it now and i don`t get any errors but my program doesn`t do what is expected regarding this function.

Comment: @Suncatcher.Please find above in the initial code an update, but still no output .If you have some advice :)

Comment: @dragospirnut, you fill `wa_cids` structure wrong: you fill on line 56 `lTDNAME`, but there should be `wa_cids-lTDNAME`, alike line 54. And there should be **single APPEND** for all that stuff, not two! Also check that your logon language (`sy-langu` on line 73) is identical with your texts language. All other is fine.

Comment: @dragospirnut, if you wanna fetch all languages, just remove line 73.

Comment: i updated as below still no output :(                                                        IF
  wa_cids-cid = 'GRUN'.
  wa_cids-cobject = 'MATERIAL'.

 elseif  cID = '0001'.
    concatenate lMVKE-MATNR lMVKE-VKORG lMVKE-VTWEG into wa_cids-lTDNAME.
  else.
    wa_cids-lTDNAME = lMVKE-MATNR.
  endif.
  append wa_cids to it_cids.

Comment: then your cID never equals 0001 and never GRUN or there could be thousands reasons. Just remove all conditions, fill the structure with literals ans its **just works ©**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think is too complicate. I am thinking of returning to read_text and do somehow to call the function read_text with a case code.

Comment: @Suncatcher.i think i will stick with read_text or read_multiple_text.Do you have any example for read_text or read_multiple_text for which i could read more multiple ID on all languages maintained?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an internal table of cIDs & cObjects like this:

```
types: begin of cids,
         cid(4)      type c,
         cobject(10) type c,
       end of cids.

data: wa_cids type cids.
data: it_cids type standard table of cids.
```

Then you can simply append all the different types of cIDs/cObjects you have to your internal table:

```
wa_cids-cid = 'GRUN'.
wa_cids-cobject = 'MATERIAL'.

append wa_cids to it_cids.
```

Then loop over your internal table calling function 'READ_TEXT'

```
loop at it_cids into wa_cids.
  call function 'READ_TEXT'
    exporting
      client   = sy-mandt
      id       = wa_cids-cid
      language = lt002-spras  "p_SPRAS
      name     = ltdname
      object   = wa_cids-cobject
    tables
      lines    = it_tline
    exceptions
      id       = 1
      others   = 8.

* Do what you need to do with it_tline here.

endloop.

* Rest of code here
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, i am looking to retrieve multiple cID for all languages that are maintained.

Comment: Hi , i tried what you advised and is not working . Can you please tell me if you have other ideea? thank you .